# Creating an email to forward mails to several recipients

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, mailing-list

How can I create an email that forwards mails to several recipients?

For instance, I would like to create an email named: `organizers_event@gmail.com`, and this email forwards mails to: `xxx@gmail.com` and `yyy@gmail.com`. Can I call it a mail-list?

One way to achieve this is by creating a new email and then forward received emails. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT

(following [the comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153582/creating-an-email-to-forward-mails-to-several-reciepants/153608?noredirect=1#comment140107_153608))

> Sorry @marikamitsos if I wasn't clear. Me with my friends want to create an "email address" that when someone send a mail to it, all of us receive the sent mail.

As stated in the [official Google help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en-GB#null&zippy=%2Cturn-automatic-forwarding-on-or-off%2Cforward-to-more-than-one-account)

> **Forward to more than one account**
> You can only automatically forward all your messages to one account.

#### Work-around

**You can create a similar condition though using filters.**

**Google Mail *(GMail)*, can filter forward to ONLY one email at a time**.
So we will use a couple of repeatable steps.

*(You have already created your account e.g. `forall@gmail.com`)*

**Step 1.**
Go to `Forwarding and POP/IMAP`--> `Add a forwarding address`.
Follow and complete ALL stages **for each individual email address you want to forward to**.
*(like `friend01@somemail.com`, `friend02@gmail.com`, `specialfriend@business.info` etc.)*

**Step 2.**
Go to `Filters and blocked addresses`.
At the bottom of the page find and click on `Create a new filter`

**Step 3.**
On the pop up ONLY complete the `To` field with the current account's address *(`forall@gmail.com`)*.
Click `Continue` and check the box for `Forward it to`.
Select one email *(`friend01@somemail.com`)* from the dropdown.
*(You may also want to add a label as well at this point)*
Click `Create Filter`.

Repeat steps **Step 2** and **Step 3** for each email address *( `friend02@gmail.com`, `specialfriend@business.info` etc.)*.

**Step 4.**
Test that all is working correctly by sending an email to `forall@gmail.com` from a different account *(`othermail@abc.com`)*

**Step 5.**
All done. Enjoy :)

***PRO NOTE***
***The above technique is great** since spam emails that are usually sent by bots omitting the recipients email address are filtered out and not forwarded.*

---

**Original reply**

I have to admit I am a bit confused by what you are trying to do. Still.

The notion itself of "forwarding" lies in the fact that you first receive an email that you then send on to a different destination.

What you probably mean is to send the email as `CC` (Carbon Copy) or `BCC` (Blind Carbon Copy).

In this case you can **address the email `To` just one recipient (even to your own mailbox) and then add the rest as `CC` or `BCC`**.

Comment: Sorry @marikamitsos if I wasn't clear. Me with my friends want to create an "email address" that when someone send a mail to it, all of us receive the sent mail.